# Creating AES session key for Cipurse (Java Card)?

Tags: aes, javacard, mutual-authentication

I try to get into cipher, mutual authenticate and such and figured it might be good to see what is "on" the market. Now, cipurse states in its specifications a term like this to generate the session key:

```
k0 = AES (key = PAD2 (kP) XOR PAD (rT), kID) XOR kID
```

where k0 is the session key, kP is an on-card calculated key, rT is the response from the terminal. PAD stands for padding (leading zeroes), PAD 2 for double padding (leading zeros) and kID is the secret key from the card.

Now as far as I am aware I create a key this way:

```
    AESKey k0_pre = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_DESELECT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
    k0_pre.clearKey();
    k0_pre.setKey(key, (short) 0);
```

Now the one question I have is concerning just a little comma nameingly

> key = PAD2 (kP) XOR PAD (rT)**,** kID

setKey takes a `byte[]` and an offset, kID is not an offset cleary - should this comma be and "AND" or should those two expressions should be concatenated or something completely different?

The example kID in the guidelines is

```
53 45 43 5f 4d 45 4d 4f 52 59 20 4b 45 59 20 31
```

The result after for `PAD2 (kP) XOR PAD (rT)` is

```
00 00 00 00 b7 a0 d2 cb 01 15 25 3f c4 0d 43 8f
```

and the k0_pre is then to be:

```
72 4b e3 3e 05 47 b5 99 9c 78 13 9d 8b 25 94 e6
```

I just don't know how this AES Key is generated out of "2" input keys

Comment: That open standard is only available to members. Must be a new definition of open I was not aware of. Then again, above seems to be a key derivation mechanism I was not aware of either.

Comment: the membership to only read the specs is for free at least but I agree! Can I send you the crypthographic spec in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer some place else:

*The encryption of a 128-bit message block m using a 128-bit key k using the advanced encryption standard
AES is denoted by* `c := AES (key = k, m).`

So, for my question the secret key kID is the message block, now it all makes sense!